# Gmail Add-on Error: SubmitFormResponseMarkup has disallowed value:card_navigations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I have function `logoutAction(e)` and when use `setOnClickAction()` and set this function on the `TextButton` in `Card` - it works fine.

But when I use the same function from `universalActions` - I get this error:

> SubmitFormResponseMarkup has disallowed value:card_navigations

```
function logoutAction(e) {
    revokeToken();

    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();

    userProperties.setProperty('loggedIn', 'false');

    // Create a Navigation object to push the card onto the stack.
    // Return a built ActionResponse that uses the navigation object.
    var nav = CardService.newNavigation().pushCard(loginFormBuild(e));
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(nav).build();
}
```

Here works fine:

```
   var logoutButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText("Logout")
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("logoutAction"));
    content.addWidget(logoutButton);
```

But from `universalActions` in manifest - it doesn`t work:

```
    "universalActions": [{
    "text": "Logout",
    "runFunction": "logoutAction"
  }]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I'm trying to reproduce your error, but I noticed your function ```logoutAction(e)``` calls two other functions first that you didn't provide, which are ```revokeToken();``` and ```getOAuthService();```. Could you please put them in your question? It would make the troubleshooting easier.

Comment: @albertovielma Thank you very much for your response. I just found the solution: we can't use the same function for simple actions and for universal actions. Because simple action must return `ActionResponse`, but universal actions must return `UniversalActionResponse`

Comment: Ok! I'm glad to hear you could find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use the same function for simple actions and for universal actions. Because simple action must return `ActionResponse`, but universal actions must return `UniversalActionResponse`.

So instead of `CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()` we need to use `CardService.newUniversalActionResponseBuilder()`

Answer (score 1):

As @Roman suggested, you should use **UniversalActionResponseBuilder()** when performing navigation operations for universal actions. Your code should be changed to

```
function logoutAction(e) {
    revokeToken();

    var service = getOAuthService();
    service.reset();

    userProperties.setProperty('loggedIn', 'false');

    return CardService.newUniversalActionResponseBuilder().displayAddOnCards([loginFormBuild(e).build()]).build();
}
```

Depending on what your function **loginFormBuild(e)** returns, you might or might not need its related build() function.